# HTML5/JQM android app structure

Tags: html, cordova, geolocation, jquery-mobile

I have been working on an app and have found many bits to do the things I need, however there seem to be so many ways to accomplish the task, I thought I would ask the experts which way they would go.

So, how to structure the app in question...

Idea, an app which will guide you through a village using GPS geolocation and when you reach points of interest (maybe 20 or so), the app will alert you and narrate the info to you (media file) and maybe show some relevant photos.

Using HTML5, JQM and phonegap (Android), I have geolocation working on one #page, showing the current location and then triggering a page change when the distance to the place is close enough, it then plays an audio file located on a web server.

I have currently got a multi page setup, but it is getting confusing when I am trying to add more points of interest and showing different maps etc. and internal page navigation is proving tricky.
I have reached a point in the build and now wonder how to proceed without it upsetting what is already working.

For functionality, is multi page the way to go? If so, how should I structure it? 
Should each time a point is reached, it opens a new #page and then runs an event on that page?
Store all the narrative mp3 files locally or on a server?
Store all the map coords in an array and reference them, how?

Any suggestions please?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is several things to consider when you are using one page architecture or multipage architecture.

Using one page architecture, all your "pages" reside in a html file. So the javascript will be loaded once.

Using multipage archicture, it will be easier to maintain the pages. But as you change the page, depending on what you use to change the page, the javscript may be reloaded.

If you are using jqm's changePage, it will load the first "page" div while if you are using plain javascript reload to change the page, all the javascript will be reloaded.

Personally, I use a mix of these two. Depending on how I structure my project.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read and answer this for me.
I am wondering if I may have to use a mixture of things in order to get it to do what is needed. I do have to consider the load time and overall size of the app, but I can't decide on how it should all go together.

Comment: I have just found an article for an app which may give me some more options for my structure. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/build-an-exercise-tracking-app-persistence-graphing/ gives a nice clean build IMHO.